# is there a way to keep jupyter lab centered on curser/ a command to do so?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

so what I would like to do is either something like `zz` in `vim` (a command to centre screen on the current cursor position) or set something like `set scrolloff` in `vim` (this will make sure the screen starts to move down when I reach the bottom/top).

here is an image of what it currently looks like:

[image]

what I would like to have by default ideally

[image]